# Open Safari Passwords pane with AppleScript or Shell script

Tags: macos, applescript, safari

I'm trying to find a way to open the Safari Passwords pane without opening Safari - similar to how Siri opens it when you ask "Show me my passwords" on macOS. Any ideas?

I'm thinking some kind of URL scheme but I cannot find anything for Safari registered in launch services. Get a list with:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -dump | grep 'bindings:'.'*:'`

Ultimately, I am trying to create a service or keyboard shortcut to open the passwords pane to quickly find a password when outside of Safari. I am not trying to bypass user authentication.

**Update:** Currently working on the assumption that the pane is a part of Safari's SiriKit handler object and so far this is the only way to open the pane outside of Safari, that is, only Siri can open the pane. Does anyone know where the `.intentdefinition` file is for Safari?

**Update 2:** Looking at file activity it seems to be an XPC Service. Is there a way to see what launchd is doing there, or replicate the call?

Comment: TBH/ since the pane is only openable whilst running Safari, I'm not sure how one can open the pane without running Safari. I would guess that Apple is very keen on protecting the contents of the database which stores the passwords from access outside of the carefully coded method they use to keep it secure in Safari.

Comment: You can access stored passwords in Terminal using the `security` command so I wouldn't think it'd be a big deal to trigger the passwords preferences pane.

Comment: I think the pane is a UI element controlled by code in Safari which accesses the security framework data which can _also_ be obtained via the `security` terminal command. When you look at the password items, you are working with the contents of keychains, both local to the machine and iCloud. If you are trying to open the pane in an attempt to bypass the local user password entry, you may be out of luck.

Comment: Those all directly use the system keychain API - what _exactly_ are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @IconDaemon I am not trying to bypass the local user authentication

Comment: @red_menace I am ultimately trying to create a service or keyboard to shortcut to open the passwords pane.

Comment: Updated my question with more info - I checked out file activity and launchd starts a XPC service with Safari.. is there a way to see whats happening there?